# Utf-8 problems with Python 3

Tags: python, json, flask

We've read from here to the moon, and the other group working on something similar does not encounter the problem at all. We are using JSON and JSON.load to read a set of questions from Flask and outputting it to an HTML file. The problem is that python doesn't read the special characters (æ ø and å) correctly.

We have tried writing straight in the HTML template, that works. Writing from Python to HTML also works, but printing either to the console or to the HTML template after reading the JSON document with json.load(f) it doesn't work at all.

Any help at finding the problem is greatly appreciated!

[For reference, this is how the text looks printed now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeBeC.jpg)

[image: result]

Here is the python code, everything but this and a proxy error is working fine!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from methods import result
import json
app = Flask(__name__)

with open('./static/data.json') as data:
    j = json.load(data)

print(j['spm'][6]['q'])

# Variables
answers = []
winners_alt = []
g = 0

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/<page>')
def index(page=None):
    if page == None:
        reset()
        return render_template('index.html')
    else:
        return render_template('slides.html', question=j['spm'][0]['q'],     varBtn="Neste Spørsmål", check="")

@app.route('/next', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def next():
    global g
    global answers
    global winners_alt
    answers.append(request.form['input'])

    if request.form['sender'] == 'NEXT':
        if g == len(j['spm'])-1:
            result(answers, j, winners_alt)
            return render_template('done.html', rankings=winners_alt)
        else:
            g += 1

            if request.method == 'POST':
                if g == len(j['spm'])-2:
                    return render_template('slides.html', question=j['spm'][g]['q'], varBtn = "Fullfør", check="")
                else:
                    return render_template('slides.html', question=j['spm'][g]['q'], varBtn = "Neste Spørsmål", check="")

@app.route('/restart', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def restart():
    reset()

    # Returning user to the startpage
    return render_template('index.html')

def reset():
    # Resetting all variables
    global g
    global answers
    g = 0
    del answers[:]
    del winners_alt[:]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

And for good measure, index 0 of the 'spm' array in data.json to show the formatting and how the question should look.

```
{ 
    "id": 1,
    "q": "Er du glad i å jobbe med teori hele dagen uten noen form for praktiske øvelser?",
    "vekt": [
        [8, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 4, 5, 5, 5, 2]
    ]
}
```

Comment: I’m guessing your system encoding is not UTF-8 and/or your web server is claiming content is not UTF-8 and is instead ISO-8859-1 (for example). What does the `Content-Type` header on responses say? Are you sure your files are getting saved in UTF-8?

Comment: All files are getting saved in UTF-8, we dont't have content-type in the header, but a meta charset="utf-8". If we write directly from python it works, if we write in html it works, it only when we read from json it doesnt work

Comment: @Hagland: Are you sure the JSON was encoded as UTF-8?

Comment: Does setting `app.config['JSON_AS_ASCII'] = False` helps. Or may be yu my try this :  `j = json.load(data.encode('utf-8'))`